# How can I have a suffix on all source fields names Mapstruct?

Tags: mapstruct, suffix

I have the following case:

```
**public class SimpleSource {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    // getters and setters
}
 
public class SimpleDestination {
    private String name__c;
    private String description__c;
    // getters and setters
 ContactMapper contactMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ContactMapper.class);
    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "name__c")
    @Mapping(source = "description", target = "description__c")

    Target__c customerContact(Source source);**
```

How can I avoid adding this @Mapping for all fields and just said that target has **suffix** "**__c**" targetFieldName = sourceFieldName+suffix

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct uses its `AccessorNamingStrategy` SPI to detect names of properties.

This means that in order to achieve what you are looking for you'll need to provide you own `AccessorNamingStrategy`.

You can read more about it in the [MapStruct Documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy)